# get data of specific user from rest api in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, rest, flutter-http

everyone I have build a rest API which has one to one relationship from parent to child. one parent can have many children.

this could be possible link of endpoint
https://example.com/api/child?email=abc@gmail.com
and My json result is

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "chi",
        "pin": 123123,
        "parent_id": 1,
        "avatar_id": null,
        "created_at": "2020-12-22T13:27:59.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-12-22T13:27:59.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "chi",
        "pin": 123123,
        "parent_id": 1,
        "avatar_id": null,
        "created_at": "2020-12-22T13:30:35.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-12-22T13:30:35.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "jazzzz",
        "pin": 12121212,
        "parent_id": 1,
        "avatar_id": null,
        "created_at": "2020-12-22T17:00:07.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-12-22T17:00:07.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "jazzzz",
        "pin": 12121212,
        "parent_id": 1,
        "avatar_id": null,
        "created_at": "2020-12-22T17:00:57.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-12-22T17:00:57.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "jazzzz",
        "pin": 12121212,
        "parent_id": 1,
        "avatar_id": null,
        "created_at": "2020-12-22T17:01:18.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-12-22T17:01:18.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "chi",
        "pin": 123123,
        "parent_id": 1,
        "avatar_id": null,
        "created_at": "2020-12-23T09:05:34.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-12-23T09:05:34.000000Z"
    }
]
```

}

my model file is

```
 class ChildModel {
  List<Data> data;

  ChildModel({this.data});

  ChildModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = new List<Data>();
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data.add(new Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  int id;
  String name;
  int pin;
  int parentId;
  Null avatarId;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;

  Data(
      {this.id,
      this.name,
      this.pin,
      this.parentId,
      this.avatarId,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    pin = json['pin'];
    parentId = json['parent_id'];
    avatarId = json['avatar_id'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['pin'] = this.pin;
    data['parent_id'] = this.parentId;
    data['avatar_id'] = this.avatarId;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    return data;
  }
}
```

I want to show all children in listview whose parent_id is 1.
I don't Know how to achieve this in a flutter. Anyone help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should first make api call using http. Then parse json response into list of your model class. Then use ListView or whatever widget you prefer to display the data.

```
var res = await http.get(API_URL)
var json = jsonDecode(res.body)
var data = json['data'].map((e)=>ChildModel.fromJson(e)).toList()
```

There is a comprehensive explanation in [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) about how to render data in ListView.

Overall you can create a stateful widget that displays data from the state. It should calls `fetchData()` method from `onCreated()` method of state class and then call `setState((){});` after data is loaded if the widget is mounted. Although this is not good practice, it is good enough to get started.

Comment: Hi sir, Thankyou for your reply. I tried this method but it shows._TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>')

Comment: @imran that error probably means API is not returning the list in the data field as shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by changing model class

```
   ChildModel childModelFromJson(String str) =>
    ChildModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

List<ChildModel> childModelListFromJson(String str) => List<ChildModel>.from(
    json.decode(str)["data"].map((x) => ChildModel.fromJson(x)));

String childModelToJson(ChildModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());
```